# Rails adding float validation to text_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, floating-point

On my view I have already added similar validation for input fields and works fine. There is two other float fields that are text_fields, when I use the same logic as before it does not work.

```
  .control-group
    %label.control-label{ for: 'holding[lat]' }= t('Geo_location')
    .controls
      = f.text_field :lat, input_html: { step: '0.000001', max: 99.999999 }, placeholder: 'Max 99.999999'
      %br
      = f.text_field :lng, input_html: { step: '0.000001', max: 99.999999, min: -99.999999 }, placeholder: 'Max -99.999999'
```

Is there another way to do something similar?

This is the field it does work for-
= f.input :quantity_acres, label: t('Number_of_acres'), input_html: { step: '0.01', max: 999999.99 }, placeholder: 'Max 999999.99'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this validation in your model

```rb
validates :lat, :lng, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: -99.999999, less_than_or_equal_to: 99.999999 }
```

Or if you have different MIN MAX values for `lat` and `lng` you can add two validations

```rb
validates :lat, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: MIN_FOR_LAT, less_than_or_equal_to: MAX_FOR_LAT }
validates :lng, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: MIN_FOR_LNG, less_than_or_equal_to: MAX_FOR_LNG }
```

Replace `MIN_FOR_LAT`, `MAX_FOR_LAT`, `MIN_FOR_LNG`, `MAX_FOR_LNG` with your numbers

It also perfectly works when `lat` and `lng` are strings

For validation before sending the form you can use one of these examples depending on your form builder

`simple_form`

```rb
= simple_form_for :your_record do |f|
  = f.input :lat, as: :integer, input_html: { step: 0.000001, max: 99.999999, min: -99.999999 }
  = f.submit
```

`form_for`

```rb
= form_for :your_record do |f|
  = f.number_field :lat, step: 0.000001, max: 99.999999, min: -99.999999
  = f.submit
```

`semantic_form`

```rb
= semantic_form_for :your_record, html: { novalidate: false } do |f|
  = f.inputs do
    = f.input :lat, as: :number, step: 0.000001, max: 99.999999, min: -99.999999
  = f.actions do
    = f.action :submit
```

Tested in `Chrome Version 100.0.4896.127 (Official Build) (x86_64)`

Comment: While this does work, I need the validation to work before the user clicks save, as in as they are typing in the data into the field.

Comment: If you use simple_for_for you can write = f.input :lat, as: :integer, input_html: { step: 0.000001, max: 99.999999, min: -99.999999 } or its analogue for other form builders. The main key here to specify integer field type

Comment: @StefanyukYuriy not sure I understand the overall semantics but neither one of those values is an Integer since Integers are categorically whole numbers.

Comment: Ended up using           = f.number_field :lat, step: '0.000001', max: '99.999999', min: '-99.999999', placeholder: 'Latitude Max 99.999999'